# How to color the right choice and the wrong choice in java script quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to color the button with green when user choice the correct answer, and with red when it is wrong but in a same time with color the correct answer with green i try this but it is not work.

this text is to let me to publish the post

/*
I would like to be able to show the user what the correct answer to the question is if the one that they selected was incorrect. I would like to keep it simple, but here is what I am thinking. Once the user submits their answer and if it is incorrect, before moving onto the next question I would like for the incorrect answer to be highlighted in red, and the correct answer to be highlighted in green.

I already have coded whether or not the answer is correct or incorrect, but I haven't been able to figure out how to be able to show the correct answer if an incorrect one is chosen.
*/

```js
function wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
   }
 }


function Quiz(questions) {
    this.score = 0;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.questionIndex = 0;
}
 
Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
    return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}
 
Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
    if(this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
        console.log(answer);
        this.score++;
    }

    populateV2();   
    wait(2000);
    this.questionIndex++;
}
 
Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
    return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}
 
 
function Question(text, textAnswer, choices, answer) {
    this.text = text;
    this.textAnswer = textAnswer;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.answer = answer;
}
 
Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
    document.getElementById("btn0").style.backgroundColor='green';
    return this.answer === choice;

}

 
function populate() {
    if(quiz.isEnded()) {
        showScores();
    }
    else {
        // show question
        var element = document.getElementById("question");
        element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

        
        // show textAnswer
        var textAnswer = quiz.getQuestionIndex().textAnswer;
        for(var i = 0; i < textAnswer.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("textAnswer" + i);
            element.innerHTML = textAnswer[i];
        }
 
        // show options
        var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
            element.innerHTML = choices[i];
            guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
        }
 
        showProgress();
    }
};

function populateV2() {
       
        console.log("Test");
        // show question
        var element = document.getElementById("question");
        element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

        
        // show textAnswer
        var textAnswer = quiz.getQuestionIndex().textAnswer;
        for(var i = 0; i < textAnswer.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("textAnswer" + i);
            element.innerHTML = textAnswer[i];
        }
 
        // show options
        var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
            element.innerHTML = choices[i];
        }
 
        showProgress();
    
};
 
function guess(id, guess) {
    var button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.onclick = function() {
        quiz.guess(guess);
        populate();
        
    }
};
 
 
function showProgress() {
    var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
    var element = document.getElementById("progress");
    element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};
 
function showScores() {
    var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
    gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
    var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
    element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};
 
// create questions here
var questions = [
    new Question("1.At what age was Harry Potter when he received his Hogwarts letter?",
    ["A: 9",
    "B: 6",
    "C: 7"],
     ["A", "B","C"],
      "C"),
    new Question("2.Which is not a Hogwarts house?",
    ["A: Dunder Mifflin",
    "B: Ravenclaw",
    "C: Slytherin"],
     ["A", "B","C"],
      "A"),
    new Question("3.Who teaches Transfiguration at Hogwarts?",
    ["A: Rubeus Hagrid",
    "B: Minerva McGonnagle",
    "C: Albus Dumbledore"],
     ["A", "B","C"],
      "B")
];
 
// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);
 
// display quiz
populate();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.grid h1 {
    font-family: "sans-serif";
    background-color: #57636e;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#score {
    color: #5A6772;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.grid #question {
    font-family: "monospace";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5A6772;
}

.grid1 #textAnswer {
    font-family: "monospace";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #5A6772;
}

.image {
    width: 20%;
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn0, #btn1 {
    background-color: #778897;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #1D3C6A;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 10px 40px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

#btn2 {
    background-color: #778897;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #1D3C6A;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}


#btn0:hover, #btn1:hover, #btn2:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #57636e;
}

#btn0:focus, #btn1:focus, #btn2:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#progress {
    color: #2b2b2b;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="quiz">
            <h1>Quiz</h1>
            <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

            <p id="question"></p>

            <ul class="grid1">
                <li id="textAnswer0"></li>
                <li id="textAnswer1"></li>
                <li id="textAnswer2"></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
                <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
                <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
            </div>
             <span id="wrong_answer"></span>
            <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
            <footer>
                <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to color the right choice with green and the wrong choices with red just select all buttons, compare the content of their `<span>` element with the right answer and color them accordingly:

```js
function wait(ms) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while (end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}


function Quiz(questions) {
  this.score = 0;
  this.questions = questions;
  this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
  return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
  if (this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
    console.log(answer);
    this.score++;
  }

  populateV2();
  wait(2000);
  this.questionIndex++;
}

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
  return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}


function Question(text, textAnswer, choices, answer) {
  this.text = text;
  this.textAnswer = textAnswer;
  this.choices = choices;
  this.answer = answer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
  var answer = this.answer;
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var letter = buttons[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].textContent;
    if (letter == answer) {
      buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else {
      buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  }
  return this.answer === choice;
}


function populate() {
  if (quiz.isEnded()) {
    showScores();
  } else {
    // show question
    var element = document.getElementById("question");
    element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;


    // show textAnswer
    var textAnswer = quiz.getQuestionIndex().textAnswer;
    for (var i = 0; i < textAnswer.length; i++) {
      var element = document.getElementById("textAnswer" + i);
      element.innerHTML = textAnswer[i];
    }

    // show options
    var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
      var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
      element.innerHTML = choices[i];
      guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
    }

    showProgress();
  }
};

function populateV2() { 
  console.log("Test");
  // show question
  var element = document.getElementById("question");
  element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;


  // show textAnswer
  var textAnswer = quiz.getQuestionIndex().textAnswer;
  for (var i = 0; i < textAnswer.length; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById("textAnswer" + i);
    element.innerHTML = textAnswer[i];
  }

  // show options
  var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
    element.innerHTML = choices[i];
  }

  showProgress();

};

function guess(id, guess) {
  var button = document.getElementById(id);
  button.onclick = function() {
    quiz.guess(guess);  
    populate();

  }
};


function showProgress() {
  var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
  var element = document.getElementById("progress");
  element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};

function showScores() {
  var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
  gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
  var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
  element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};

// create questions here
var questions = [
  new Question("1.At what age was Harry Potter when he received his Hogwarts letter?",
    ["A: 9",
      "B: 6",
      "C: 7"
    ],
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    "C"),
  new Question("2.Which is not a Hogwarts house?",
    ["A: Dunder Mifflin",
      "B: Ravenclaw",
      "C: Slytherin"
    ],
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    "A"),
  new Question("3.Who teaches Transfiguration at Hogwarts?",
    ["A: Rubeus Hagrid",
      "B: Minerva McGonnagle",
      "C: Albus Dumbledore"
    ],
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    "B")
];

// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display quiz
populate();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.grid h1 {
    font-family: "sans-serif";
    background-color: #57636e;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#score {
    color: #5A6772;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.grid #question {
    font-family: "monospace";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5A6772;
}

.grid1 #textAnswer {
    font-family: "monospace";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #5A6772;
}

.image {
    width: 20%;
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn0, #btn1 {
    background-color: #778897;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #1D3C6A;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 10px 40px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

#btn2 {
    background-color: #778897;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #1D3C6A;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}


#btn0:hover, #btn1:hover, #btn2:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #57636e;
}

#btn0:focus, #btn1:focus, #btn2:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#progress {
    color: #2b2b2b;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
        <div id="quiz">
            <h1>Quiz</h1>
            <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

            <p id="question"></p>

            <ul class="grid1">
                <li id="textAnswer0"></li>
                <li id="textAnswer1"></li>
                <li id="textAnswer2"></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
                <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
                <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
            </div>
             <span id="wrong_answer"></span>
            <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
            <footer>
                <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note that you have to adjust/restructure your code so that there's a short waiting time before the new question is generated as I think you might want to show the buttons again with the grey background color upon a new question.